# Why are there 2 Clementines on the Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: 16.04, software-center, clementine

I wanted to install Clementine and noticed 2 of them in the Ubuntu Software Center, as shown in the image:

[image: Clementine in Ubuntu Software screenshot]

Is there a difference between the two? Are they both different versions? Or is something more shady going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's nothing shady going on. The first one is a [snap package](https://docs.snapcraft.io/snaps/intro), deployed by a new package management system called *snappy* built by Canonical (the Ubuntu company). You can try any of them.