# Why are there 2 packages for some applications (e.g. Chromium) in Ubuntu Software?

Tags: software-installation, software-center

When I search for Chromium in Ubuntu Software on Ubuntu 16.04, There are 2 options.

[image: When I search for Chromium in Ubuntu Software, There are 2 images. Which one Do I select?]

Which one should I select?

---

The same can be observed with [VLC media player](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985564/what-is-the-difference-between-vlc-and-vlc-media-player-in-ubuntu-software-i), [Clementine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964392/why-are-there-2-clementines-on-the-ubuntu-software-center), [Inkscape](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037995/why-are-there-two-inkscape-entries-in-ubuntu-software?) etc.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first and the third items are both the Chromium browser. The former is a snap package and the latter is a Debian package.

You can confirm this from the version numbers and descriptions. The first:

[image]

matches:

```
$ snap search chromium
Name      Version       Developer  Notes  Summary
chromium  62.0.3202.75  canonical  -      Chromium web browser, open-source version of Chrome
```

The second:

[image]

matches:

```
$ apt search chromium-browser
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
chromium-browser/xenial-updates,xenial-security 62.0.3202.75-0ubuntu0.16.04.1313 amd64
  Chromium web browser, open-source version of Chrome
```

and the [AppStream](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Distributions/AppStream/) description:

```
$ appstreamcli search chromium
Identifier: chromium-browser.desktop [desktop-application]
Name: Chromium Web Browser
Summary: Access the Internet
Package: chromium-browser
Icon: chromium-browser_chromium-browser.png
```

Using the `gnome-software` command should help. Both of these commands open the third entry:

```
gnome-software --details=chromium-browser.desktop
gnome-software --details-pkg=chromium-browser
```

Here, `chromium-browser.desktop` is the AppStream ID, and `chromium-browser` is the package name.

Comment: So the way to tell a snap package from a Debian package is whether it has a star rating or not. That is... not intuitive to say the least.

Comment: How can we tell Canonical about this? This is really, really user unfriendly!!

Comment: @saitam I believe they updated Ubuntu Software  to show the source of the app (to say "Source: Snap" if it's snap).