# Read-only filesystem for a folder related to VLC Player

Tags: filesystem, vlc

I was watching video using VLC player when my computer turned off (power outage). And when I turned it on and logged in, VLC was unable to start.

I tried to remove VLC (`sudo apt remove`...), and this command executed without any error messages.

There is a folder `/snap/vlc` with subfolders, which cannot be deleted. When I try to delete it via Midnight Commander (started via `sudo mc`) I get

```
Unable to delete folder, read-only filesystem (30)
```

The rest of the disk is writeable, but this particular folder (with subfolders) are marked read-only filesystem.

I ran `fsck` for the whole disk (took 3.5 hours) and it did not find any errors.

I tried `remount rw` but the problem still persists.

What can I do to delete this folder and reinstall VLC player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you actually had VLC installed as a [snap package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985564/what-is-the-difference-between-vlc-and-vlc-media-player-in-ubuntu-software-i) instead of via traditional `apt` method.

Run the following command (with `sudo` if needed) to remove VLC

```
snap remove vlc
```