# Which VLC player should I install?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, vlc

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my desktop and restored my files from a backup drive. Unfortunately it did not restore my applications that I had installed (figured it out that I didn't backup my entire drive, only a few folders). So I had to install most of my applications either through the traditional command-line way or Ubuntu Software program. I had to install VLC as it's way better than the traditional video player. 
But I faced a problem, there are two applications with the same name 'VLC' which have the same screenshots but different developers and source. I don't know which one to install. I want a stable version that is managed by the VideoLAN developers.

Information about the two 'VLC' players are below ---

VLC #1
Channel - stable
Version - 3.0.7
License - free
Developer - VideoLAN (with a tick)
Source - Snap Store (I'm not very sure about this)

VLC #2
Version - 3.0.7.1-0ubuntu18.04.1
Updated - never
License - free
Developer - VideoLAN et al.
Source - ubuntu-bionic-updates-universe

Comment: Which one to install is completely up to you, for the differences see these: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "vlc" and "VLC media player" in Ubuntu Software in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985564/what-is-the-difference-between-vlc-and-vlc-media-player-in-ubuntu-software-i) && https://askubuntu.com/q/972411/480481

Comment: Those answers don't really explain the differences between snap and regular.  Found with a few snaps, there is a difference bewteen how they act with different permissions.  Is there an answer around that we can point to, to more fully explain?

Answer (score 2):

Last version **3.0.7.1** is a minor upgrade from the 3.0.7, so you should choose the latest, source can be trusted as the repository is ubuntu-bionic-updates-universe.

```
Changes between 3.0.7 and 3.0.7.1:
----------------------------------

Access:
 * Update libbluray to 1.1.2

macOS:
 * Fix bluray java menu playback regression in 3.0.7

Video Output:
 * Fix hardware acceleration with some AMD drivers
 * Improve direct3d11 HDR support
```

Comment: I think the question (also) is about `Source - Snap Store` and `Source - ubuntu-bionic-updates-universe`

Comment: Some Snap versions of apps tend to have permission problems, lacking of certain permissions.  If you use most of vlc's features I would go with #2, if just use to watch your plain videos either one will do.  I do not know for certain if snap vlc would be lacking.