# Can't find a .desktop shortcut for VLC in '/usr/share/applications' to copy to my desktop

Tags: 18.04, .desktop, shortcuts

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I want to create a shortcut on my desktop for a program I've just installed (VLC media player). I've already done it for Google Chrome, so I do the same and I go to `/usr/share/applications`, but I can't find any `.desktop` file related to VLC there.

*(In case you may be asking, yes I've installed GNOME Tweaks and yes I've enabled "Show icons".)*

So, how can I create a shortcut on my desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't find a `.desktop` launcher for VLC in `/usr/share/applications/`, it seems you installed the [snap version of VLC](https://askubuntu.com/q/985564/480481) instead of the traditional one. In that case you would find the associated `.desktop` file in the `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` directory.

If you wish you can also create a `.desktop` launcher manually by various GUI and CLI ways, refer to this: [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/q/13758/480481)

Comment: Thanks ! It worked perfectly, the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.10, I noticed my `vlc.desktop` was gone for some reason, which broke `xdg-open`.

I now understood that this is because I had `vlc-bin` and `vlc-data` installed, which allows me to run `vlc`, but I didn't have the `vlc` package itself for some reason I don't understand, which is the one that contains `/usr/share/applications/vlc.desktop`.

So running:

```
sudo apt install vlc
```

fetched that file and solved the issue for me.