# Why are there two Inkscape entries in Ubuntu Software?

Tags: software-center, 18.04, inkscape

[image: Ubuntu Software window with two Inkscape packages, with different descriptions but same name and icon]

I seems there are two entries of Inkscape in Ubuntu Software.

What is the difference? Which one should I install?

(Using Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the description on each:

- 0.92+devel is the 0.92 development version using a snap.

[image]

- 0.92.3.1 is the regular Ubuntu version.

[image]

> Which one should I install?

That is your choice to make.