# terminal says inkscape not installed but it is

Tags: dependencies, inkscape

running ubuntu 18.04.1 on acer laptop.
I recently upgraded from ubuntu16 to 18 doing a clean install. all works fine but inkscape. i installed from ubuntu software center.
inkscape only let me open documents from within the running application (menu, open file). if i try to open file by clicking on "open with inkscape" it gives various error popups "failed to load....mentioning only part of the path to the document i removed inkskape and reinstalled. still not working.
so i tried `sudo apt-get purge inkscape` and the terminal returns:`Package 'inkscape' is not installed, so not removed`. i don't understand, as inkscape is running, so it must be installed.
I looked up in the inkscape directory and found extension errors file. have no idea what it says, but there are a bunch of "dependecy errors" it seems.
if it helps, hereś the content of the errors file.:

```
Extension "Dia Input" failed to load because a dependency was not met.
Dependency:
  type: executable
  location: path
  string: dia
  description: In order to import Dia files, Dia itself must be installed.  You can get Dia at http://live.gnome.org/Dia

Extension "LaTeX" failed to load because a dependency was not met.
Dependency:
  type: executable
  location: path
  string: latex

Extension "LaTeX" failed to load because a dependency was not met.
Dependency:
  type: executable
  location: path
  string: dvips

Extension "GIMP XCF" failed to load because a dependency was not met.
Dependency:
  type: executable
  location: path
  string: gimp

Extension "Win32 Vector Print" failed to load because the extension is designed for Windows only.  This is caused by an improper .inx file for this extension.  An improper .inx file could have been caused by a faulty installation of Inkscape.
Extension "Sketch Input" failed to load because a dependency was not met.
Dependency:
  type: executable
  location: path
  string: skconvert
```

and last, the "theme" also  looks strange. if i remember right the version i used on ubuntu 16 felt somewhat more slick.[image: screenshot inkscape]

thanks and sorry for maybe a bit clumsy description.tried my best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have installed the [snap version](https://docs.snapcraft.io/snaps/intro) of Inkscape instead of the traditional `apt` one (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972411/why-are-there-2-packages-for-some-applications-e-g-chromium-in-ubuntu-softwar) for reference). You can verify that by running

```
snap list | grep inkscape
```

You can remove it by running

```
snap remove inkscape
```

After that, you can install the usual `apt` version by running

```
sudo apt install inkscape
```

Comment: yes, using snap remove inkscape worked, but how to install the apt version? i used the ubuntu software center. shouldnt that be the the apt version?

Comment: accepted answer!. adding that i now found 2 versions on software center. after i removed snap version using your comand. very cool, problem solved and i learned! appreciate it