# Opening identical application of two in Gnome's Applications overview opens the first one

Tags: gnome, software-center

In my Ubuntu Software there are 2 identical HexChat applications, and I installed both of them. (the reason is this [Why are there 2 Clementines on the Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964392/why-are-there-2-clementines-on-the-ubuntu-software-center) as they are the same just the source of one is ubuntu-eoan-universe and the other the Snap Store) Also on the installed size it says 79MB on first and 1MB on second in the Ubuntu Software.

Open Gnome Applications overview (click on grid bottom left) and see both.

Opening either the first one or the second one the first one opens. How come?

release of Ubuntu: 19.10

Comment: did you install both the apps from different source? is the app name `HexChat`?

Comment: Yes, from both source. On Ubuntu Software on both it says installed.

Comment: I have tried it in Ubuntu 19.10 but cant reproduce the issue.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrQ52.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNtJ9.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Likely because both versions use the same identifiers to check for a running instance. In many such apps (browsers, editors) when you invoke the program:

- it checks if some global resource exists (PID file, or else) that indicates that an instance is already running.

  - if yes, it passes the arguments to the existing instance and exits. The window opens in the existing instance.
  - if no, it creates the global resource making it point to itself, and so becomes the existing instance.

So if both versions use the same identifier for the global resource, they will share instances and you will only run the first one. There are sometimes flags to force the creation of an "isolated" instance.